# Invalid Object Name when trying to call a function

Tags: sql, function

I'm trying to use the following code to call this function, but I'm getting the following error:
Invalid object name 'fnDiscountPrice'.

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnDiscountPrice
(@ItemID int)
RETURNS money
BEGIN
RETURN
(SELECT (ItemPrice - DiscountAmount) AS DiscountPrice
FROM OrderItems 
WHERE ItemID = @ItemID);
END

SELECT * FROM fnDiscountPrice(3);
```

What is the proper way to call this function? Or is the function itself written incorrectly?

Comment: You just return a scalar value, not a table, so the syntax would be `SELECT fnDiscountPrice(3);`

Comment: That code is far from ANSI SQL compliant. Tag the dbms product you're using.